# Возможно ли запустить WPF-приложение без .NET?

Tags: c#, wpf, windowsinstaller, .net-framework

Возможно ли запустить приложение, написанное на .NET, без использования .NET Framework?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, что именно вы хотите получить, что сделали сами, что не получилось?

Comment: Жуть заминусовали. Совершенно нормальный вопрос, хотя и можно было добавить некоторых деталей, например, зачем это понадобилось — тогда ответ был бы более полным.

Answer (score 8):

На данный момент это невозможно. Запуск приложений, написанных на .NET и, соответственно, полностью полагающихся на .NET, невозможен без установки .NET Framework.

На данный момент ведётся разработка проекта .NET Native, который позволит компилировать .NET приложение в полностью независимый исполняемый файл. Он основывается на компиляторе Visual Studio C++. Однако этот проект до сих пор находится на ранней стадии разработки, и первой целью для него является Windows Store, где производительность и потребление ресурсов наиболее критичны.

В ближайшем будущем компиляция приложения WPF в полностью независимый бинарник не планируется. Вам придётся всегда устанавливать .NET Framework, что, впрочем, не должно вызывать проблем, потому что это системный компонент операционной системы, который обновляется с помощью Windows Update — достаточно всего лишь не отключать обновления.

Comment: Задумка .NET Native очень хорошая, однако упор на Windows Store все портит. Начали бы они с desktop приложений - цены бы небыло.

Comment: @z668 Десктоп слишком обширен и функционален. Windows Store — урезанная платформа, плюс железо, на котором этим приложения выполняется, слишком слабое. Я-то, конечно, тоже не в восторге от приоритета на сторе, но понять МС можно.

Comment: Уже должно работать

Comment: @VladD Пока пробовал только с Авалонией — всё ломалось.  Но что-то типа уже почти есть, да.

Answer (score 3):

Технология WPF является плоть от плоти .NET технологией, поэтому без .NET framework приложение WPF существовать не может. По крайней мере таково положение вещей на данный момент, и, насколько я знаю, ни о каких изменениях на данном поприще объявлено не было.

Answer (score 0):

Есть нечто в этом направлении под названием Spoon Studio, но оно далеко не бесплатное и имеет некоторые ограничения. Подробности тут: [ссылка](https://spoon.net/studio)